# IE7 throws "parseerror" parsing JSON using jQuery

Tags: python, json, jquery, pylons

IE7 throws an exception: `"jquery: parseerror"` when running the following code. It works in all other browsers I've tested (Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Chromium).

Script:

```
 function check(){
            $("#form").ajaxSubmit({
                url: "/send-file",
                dataType: "json",
                success:
                    function(answer){
                        $("#result").html(answer.msg);
                        },
                error:
                    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert(textStatus);

                    }
                });
            return false;
    }
```

The server script(controller of Pylons):

```
  @jsonify
    def sendFile(self):
        response.content_type = "text/plain"
        response.cache_control = 'no-cache'
        response.pragma = "no-cache, must-revalidate"
        response.expires = "-1" 

        data = dict(msg = '<h1 id="sd">ffffffffff</h1> \
                <p>ddddd</p> <a href="#">link</a>' )
        return data
```

Comment: Can you post a sample response from the server?

Comment: response from server:{"msg": "<h1 id=\"sd\">ffffffffff</h1> <p>ddddd</p><a href=\"#\">link</a>"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem seems to be in the jQuery plugin for uploading files using hidden frame. If it is the plugin, than it contains an error (if i recall correctly it reads the contents of the json from the body tag). I wanted to chat on the issue with the author, but the facebook comments in his blog raised an exception. As result, I slightly fixed the plugin locally to read the whole server result.

Unfortunatelly, I currently don't have access the hacked version.

Comment: I checked it. It's actually problem in plugin. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

instead if

```
response.content_type = "text/plain"
```

try

```
response.content_type = "application/json"
```

Comment: no. it's not work in ie. Browser try open json with another application.

Comment: Try `text/html`. IE won't open `application/json` in the browser.

Comment: It's the same error. If set header application/json ie suggests me to save the file

Comment: what does it do if you dont specify a content type ? and also try by removing this line `response.cache_control = 'no-cache'`